# Como usar .reduce com async/await?

Tags: javascript, característica-linguagem, async-await

Em código síncrono posso ter um `.reduce` para fazer um cálculo de uma soma (como neste exemplo simples de uma lista de compras):

```js
const tipos = ['leite', 'manteiga', 'pão'];
const precos = [23, 21, 32];

const buscarPreço = (tipo) => {
  const indice = tipos.indexOf(tipo);
  return precos[indice]
};

const somar = () => {
  const compras = ['leite', 'leite', 'manteiga', 'pão', 'pão', 'pão'];
  return compras.reduce((soma, tipo) => {
    const valor =  buscarPreço(tipo);
    return soma + valor;
  }, 0);
}
const soma = somar();
console.log(soma);
```

Tentei converter isto em código assíncrono e deparei-me com problemas... aparece no resultado `[object Promise]32`. Não entendi o problema uma vez que a callback do `.reduce` tem `async` declarado e dentro estou a "resolver" a promise da parte assíncrona com `const valor = await buscarPreço(tipo);`... o que me está a faltar?

Código assíncrono (que dá erro):

```js
const tipos = ['leite', 'manteiga', 'pão'];
const precos = [23, 21, 32];

const buscarPreço = (tipo) => new Promise((res) => {
  const indice = tipos.indexOf(tipo);
  setTimeout(() => res(precos[indice]), 500);
});

const somar = async() => {
  const compras = ['leite', 'leite', 'manteiga', 'pão', 'pão', 'pão'];
  return compras.reduce(async(soma, tipo, i) => {
    const valor = await buscarPreço(tipo);
    console.log('A calcular a posição', i);
    return soma + valor;
  }, 0);
}

somar().then(soma => console.log(soma));
```

Answer (score 4):

O problema (depois de meia hora) é que a callback do `.reduce`, sendo assíncrona, retorna uma promise... ou seja o primeiro argumento da callback (depois da primeira iteração) é uma Promise.

Para poder usar o valor que está a ser somado é preciso resolver a Promise

```
return compras.reduce(async(_soma, tipo, i) => {
  const soma = await _soma;
```

E para isso funcionar na primeira iteração é necessário passar `Promise.resolve(0)` como valor inicial (segundo argumento) do `.reduce(callback, segundoArgumento)`.

A solução esquemática é:

```js
  return umaArray.reduce(async(<_promise>, valorIterado) => {
    const acumulado = await <_promise>;
    // algo assíncrono;
    return ...
  }, Promise.resolve(<valor inicial>));
```

E o exemplo a funcionar:

```js
const tipos = ['leite', 'manteiga', 'pão'];
const precos = [23, 21, 32];

const buscarPreço = (tipo) => new Promise((res) => {
  const indice = tipos.indexOf(tipo);
  setTimeout(() => res(precos[indice]), 500);
});

const somar = async() => {
  const compras = ['leite', 'leite', 'manteiga', 'pão', 'pão', 'pão'];
  return compras.reduce(async(_soma, tipo, i) => {
    const soma = await _soma;
    const valor = await buscarPreço(tipo);
    console.log('A calcular a posição', i);
    return soma + valor;
  }, Promise.resolve(0));
}

somar().then(soma => console.log(soma));
```